# how to pass date value to @inputText in PlayFramework

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I want to create a form where by default when form is loaded it will set current date in format "dd.MM.yyyy" I tried to insert it via value in @inputText but it is not working:

```
@inputText(
                postForm("postedAt"),
                'value->(new Date().format("dd.mm.yyyy")) ,
                'type->"date",
                '_label->"Date",
                '_showConstraints->false,
                'class -> "form-control",
                'required -> "required")
```

Still input value is not showing current date:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWaZP.png]

Any idea how to pass the data display it in `@inputText`?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `date` field as documented [here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Forms$@date(pattern:String,timeZone:java.util.TimeZone):play.api.data.Mapping[java.util.Date])? For ex. in your form definition, you could bind the `postedAt` field as:

```
Form( ...
  "postedAt" -> date("dd.MM.yyyy")
  ...
)
```

Then fill the `postedAt` field in the form with `new Date()` in your `Action` and then, in your template, display its value like

```
@inputText(postForm("postedAt"),
   'type -> "date",
   '_label -> "Date",
   '_showConstraints -> false,
   'class -> "form-control",
   'required -> "required")
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should work as advertised.

Comment: I implemented this as you described but still date is not showing up.